# How to remove specific rows in Excel

Tags: excel, filter

I have an Excel sheet that is grouped by two columns:

1. AccountNumber (Column F)
   and then,
2. InsertDate (Column E)

I would like to filter the sheet so it would leave a row for each account number with the latest date.

Take a look at my screenshot below, I've marked in green the rows the I would like to keep.

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple formula for this (I did it on the A-column):

```
=OR(NOT(A2=A3),A3="")
```

It means that:

- either this row and the next one are different
- either the next row is empty

In a simple example, it looks as follows (at the last row, the value is `TRUE`, else it is `FALSE`):

[image]

You just use that formula for conditional formatting.